# GGPLOT : How to add 2nd Y axis Labels for Mean and Standard Deviation using geom_line, geom_hline, annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

Dear StackOverFlow Leaders,

I have drawn a line plot using geom_line, and I have Concentration on left side of the Y axis. I have also added Mean and Standard Deviation of the data as horizontal lines and text using geom_hline() and annotate() functions.

How can I change my R code to make the actual text of Mean and Standard Deviation values appear on right hand side of the Y axis ? Any advice/help is appreciated.

My Data :

```
Index   Country Month   Concentration
1       USA     April   17.1094
2       USA     April   16.001
3       USA     April   16.6342
4       USA     April   17.0215
5       USA     April   16.6438
6       USA     May     18.5031
7       USA     May     19.2239
8       USA     May     18.3213
9       USA     May     19.8904
10      USA     May     19.4935
```

My Script :

```
myData <- data.frame(as.matrix(read.table( "Demo_Data.txt",  sep="\t", header=TRUE )))


myData$Concentration <- as.numeric(as.character(myData$Concentration))

Mean <- round(mean(myData$Concentration, na.rm = TRUE),2)
SD <- round(sd(myData$Concentration, na.rm = TRUE),2)

ggplot(myData, aes(x = Index, y = Concentration, group=Country)) +
facet_grid(. ~Month, scales = "free", space = "free")  + 

geom_line(aes(color=Country)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=Country)) + 

### Mean
geom_hline(yintercept=Mean, color = "black", size=1) +
annotate(geom="text", x=5, y=Mean+0.2, label=paste("Mean : ", round(Mean,1), sep=""), color="black", fontface="bold") +

### Mean + (1 * SD)
geom_hline(yintercept=Mean+SD, color = "black", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
annotate(geom="text", x=5, y=Mean+SD+0.2, label=paste("+1*SD : ", round(Mean+SD,1), sep=""), color="black", fontface="bold") +

### Mean - (1 * SD)
geom_hline(yintercept=Mean-SD, color = "black", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
annotate(geom="text", x=5, y=Mean-SD-0.2, label=paste("-1*SD : ", round(Mean-SD,1), sep=""), color="black", fontface="bold") +

### Mean + (2 * SD)
geom_hline(yintercept=Mean+(2*SD), color = "black", linetype="dotted", size=1) +
annotate(geom="text", x=5, y=Mean+(2*SD)+0.2, label=paste("+2*SD : ", round(Mean+(2*SD),1), sep=""), color="black", fontface="bold") +

### Mean - (2 * SD)
geom_hline(yintercept=Mean-(2*SD), color = "black", linetype="dotted", size=1) +
annotate(geom="text", x=5, y=Mean-(2*SD)-0.2, label=paste("-2*SD : ", round(Mean-(2*SD),1), sep=""), color="black", fontface="bold") + 

theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold", colour = "black"),
strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size=14)) + 

ylim(14,21)
```

I have explored sec.axis() function, but that may not be appropriate for this case.

Both My_Current_Plot and My_Desired_Plot are posted here. The above R code generates My_Current_Plot, and Please advise on how to change/improve the code to create My_Desired_Plot

[image: My_Current_PLot]

[image: My_Desired_Plot]

Comment: Can i tweak the sec.axis() function and make it customized for my use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Making use of the "secondary axis trick" is a good option to achieve your desired result. Moreover, you could simplify your code considerablly by putting the information for your `hline`s and the labels in a dataframe:

```r
myData$Concentration <- as.numeric(as.character(myData$Concentration))

Mean <- round(mean(myData$Concentration, na.rm = TRUE),2)
SD <- round(sd(myData$Concentration, na.rm = TRUE),2)

df_hline <- data.frame(
  y = c(Mean, Mean + c(1, -1, 2, -2) * SD),
  label = c("Mean : ", "+1*SD : ", "-1*SD : ", "+2*SD : ", "-2*SD : "),
  linetype = c("solid", "dashed", "dashed", "dotted", "dotted")
)
df_hline$label <- paste0(df_hline$label, round(df_hline$y, 1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(myData, aes(x = Index, y = Concentration, group=Country)) +
  facet_grid(. ~Month, scales = "free", space = "free")  + 
  geom_line(aes(color=Country)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Country)) + 
  geom_hline(data = df_hline, aes(yintercept = y, linetype = linetype), color = "black", size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = df_hline$y, labels = df_hline$label), limits = c(14, 21)) +
  scale_linetype_identity() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size=14))
```

[image]

**EDIT** If you want to set the colors of the hlines you could do so by adding the colors to the dataframe `df_hline`. To make this work while at the same time mapping `Country` on the `color` aes you could set the colors via `scale_color_manual` which requires define a color palette for `Country`. In the code below I simply use the default ggplot2 color palette available via `scales::hue_pal`. To this color palette I add `red` and `black`. Additionally to prevent the `hline` from showing up in the legend I make use of the `breaks` argument.

```r
df_hline <- data.frame(
  y = c(Mean, Mean + c(1, -1, 2, -2) * SD),
  label = c("Mean : ", "+1*SD : ", "-1*SD : ", "+2*SD : ", "-2*SD : "),
  linetype = c("solid", "dashed", "dashed", "dotted", "dotted"),
  color = c("black", "red", "red", "red", "red")
)
df_hline$label <- paste0(df_hline$label, round(df_hline$y, 1))

pal_country <- scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(myData$Country)))
pal_country <- setNames(pal_country, unique(myData$Country))

ggplot(myData, aes(x = Index, y = Concentration, group = Country)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Month, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  geom_hline(data = df_hline, aes(yintercept = y, linetype = linetype, color = color), size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Country)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Country)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = df_hline$y, labels = df_hline$label), limits = c(14, 21)) +
  scale_linetype_identity() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(pal_country, red = "red", black = "black"), breaks = names(pal_country)) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14)
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Index = 1:10, Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), Month = c("April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "May", "May", "May", "May", 
"May"), Concentration = c(17.1094, 16.001, 16.6342, 17.0215, 
16.6438, 18.5031, 19.2239, 18.3213, 19.8904, 19.4935)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you so much. It works, But, did you notice that this graph is supposed to have 1 solid line at Mean, and 2 dashed lines at +1*SD and -1*SD.  Instead of that, this graph has 1 dashed line, and 2 solid lines

Comment: Aw. Yeah. I forgot to add the scale_linetype_identity().

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I added scale_linetype_identity() + to my script, and it works now

Comment: Is there a way to specify the colors for the dashed lines ? For Example, black color for mean horizontal line, and red lines for dotted lines ?

Comment: I tried to change the colors of the horizontal lines by this code :  geom_hline(data = df_hline, aes(yintercept = y, linetype = linetype), color = c("black", "red", "red", "red", "red"), size=1) , but I got Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): colour

Comment: Yep. Sure could we have different colors. I just made an edit to show you one approach to add colors.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I tried to change the labels from Mean and SD to greek symbols Mu 'µ' and Sigma 'σ' , but I got an error <cannot coerce class ‘"expression"’ to a data.frame>. I changed my R code for df_hline data frame as follows :   label = c(expression(paste0(mu," : ")), expression(paste0("+1", sigma," : ")), expression(paste0("-1", sigma," : ")), expression(paste0("+2", sigma," : ")), expression(paste0("-2", sigma," : ")))  . I appreciate any advice

Comment: I figured out that I can just use the layman approach, i.e. directly copy and past the greek letters label μ and σ inplace of Mean and SD in my r code, and it works label = = c("μ : ", "+1σ : ", "-1σ : ", "+2σ : ", "-2σ : ")